# How to improve fax document quality?

Tags: image-processing, ocr, text-rendering

I've been using tesseract to ocr Iban numbers from fax document which has resolution of 200x200 or 200x100 dpi. Documents are poor in quality. I'm using C#.net. How do I improve fax document and text quality to improve ocr accuracy?

Answer (score 3):

Musa:

Fax images can get sort of tricky. Initially, you could try scaling or re-sizing the off-DPI images in such a way that they corresponds to a square resolution (i.e. - 200x200).

After this, it's a matter of the content that's on the image (the text characters and their appearance). There are a number of image operations you could perform in an attempt to help make the text objects more suitable for recognition:

- Erosion: If the text objects appear to be very bold on the image, then you could attempt to erode it to thin them out.
- Dilation: The opposite of erosion. Dilation will add pixels to the objects in question. So, if the text is very thin or has small gaps, performing dilation could help.
- Handling dot-shading: If the text on the image is actually composed of black & white dots (assuming this is a 1-bit, black and white image), then dilating the image may possibly help with this. Or, converting the image to a higher bit depth, smoothing the pixels with a blur operation, and then thresholding it back down to 1-bit could help to make the text objects solid.

Hope this helps.